# ExecCommand modificar width y height en insertImage

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes. Creo que comencé en este foro con el pie izquierdo, por lo que lo vuelvo a intentar. Si ahora no me hago entender ya no molestaré más.

Como me indicó Travv, reformulo mi pregunta:

Cuando utilizo execCommand insertImage, desearía que la imagen que inserto en un campo de texto tuviese otras medidas en pixeles, por ejemplo si la imagen original es de 200 x 200 px, es posible enviar al comando insertImage la URL de la imagen y otras medidas? (por ejemplo, 100 x 100 px).

Probé lo siguiente:

```
var img; 
if(!(img=prompt('ingresar url','http://')))return; 
img.width=100+'px';
img.height=80+'px';
document.execCommand('InsertImage',false,img);
```

Pero aunque no me da error, tampoco altera a la imagen.

Espero sus respuestas, muchas gracias.

Comment: `img` es solo el string de la imagen, este no contiene atributos ancho ni alto, como lo quieres modificar, tendrías que seleccionar la imagen recién insertada y después modificar los atributos de alto y ancho antes de terminar la ejecución de tu script.

Answer (score 0):

El problema de usar `insertImage` es que no devuelve un controlador de la imagen y seleccionarla una vez creada no es sencillo, lo que complica la tarea de cambiar el tamaño.

Para poder encontrar la imagen y cambiar el tamaño, podrías optar por varias opciones, pero todas tienen algún tipo de problema:

1. Podrías usar `insertHTML` en lugar de `insertImage`. Crearías una cadena que contenga el código de una imagen en HTML con el `src`  que acabas de leer y el tamaño que quieras... el problema es que entonces el código sería vulnerable a ataques de XSS (`insertImage` tiene unas medidas de seguridad que te tendrías que saltar al crear el HTML de la `img`).
2. Podrías usar `insertImage` y luego seleccionar la imagen a partir de la fuente que se haya proporcionado. Esto sería sencillo y no tendría problemas de seguridad como el indicado antes, pero si otra imagen con la misma URL ya existe, puede ser un problema porque no sabrías cuál de ellas se seleccionaría.
3. Podrías usar `insertImage` y aprovecharte de que el cursor se coloca justo después de la imagen insertada para seleccionar el nodo anterior (aunque este comportamiento no está asegurado). Esto te aseguraría que se seleccionara la imagen que se acaba de insertar, pero es más complejo de desarrollar que las otras opciones.

Así sería con el método #2:

```js
function crearImagen() {
  var img;
  if (!(img = prompt('ingresar url', 'https://placehold.it/200x160'))) return;
  // creamos la imagen con el src indicado
  document.execCommand("insertImage", false, img);
  
  // seleccionamos la imagen que tenga ese src y cambiamos el tamaño
  var imagen = document.querySelector("img[src='" + img + "']");
  imagen.style.width = "100px";
  imagen.style.height = "80px";
}
```

```css
div { 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="crearImagen()">Crear Imagen</button>

<div contenteditable>
  Pulsa en el div y luego en el botón "Crear Imagen".
</div>
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias, Alvaro! Entendí todas las opciones que planteas, y utilizaré la segunda. Nuevamente te agradezco la ayuda.

Rubén.